# How to show text as link starts with @

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I am showing text as link in my text view by android:autoLink="web" property. And it showing successfuly. But now i also want to show text as link which starts from @, for example "FleeGroups" in word "User pressed FOH button of this post via @FleeGroups"

Comment: we can achieve this by SpannableString http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html

Comment: May you please explain it by code i never used SpannableString. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure. Will be posting the answer.

Comment: @MuhammadAamirALi will there be more `@words` in a single line?.

Comment: No there will be single @word

Comment: @MuhammadAamirALi then try my solution. also will it be always at the end?

Comment: @Raghunandan Sure i am trying your solution. Thank you so much

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes it will be always in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Spanable String

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String s= "User pressed FOH button of this post via @FleeGroups";
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
         String split[] = s.split("@");
        SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(split[1]);

        Log.i("....",""+split[0]+"........."+split[1]);
        ss1.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(split[1]), 0,split[1].length(), 0);
        tv.append(split[0]);
        tv.append(ss1);
        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan
{
     String mystring;
    public MyClickableSpan(String s)
    {
        mystring =s;
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mystring, 1000).show();

    }
}


}
```

More on styling @

http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring

Snap shot

[image]

For reference if you need it later.

You can also use a regex to match words that start with @

```
    String s= "User pressed @FOH button of this post via @FleeGroups some text";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("@\\s*(\\w+)").matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
     spanstring= matcher.group(1);
     Log.i(".............",spanstring);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Html.fromHtml()` and then set the `LinkMovementMethod` movement method.

Like this:

```
String link = "<a href=\"http://google.com\">@FleeGroups</a>";
String message = "User pressed FOH button of this post via ";

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(message + link));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: A great idea; but "fromHtml" seems to be deprecated in new SDK.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*Method in which you can pass the string to convert the into 
spannableString and call this method form where ever you want 
to set the text. It even work if you have mutiple @ symbols
 in your string.*/
```

TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setText(getSpannableString("hi @StackOverFlow android"));

```
public SpannableStringBuilder getSpannableString(String str) {

        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        String feed = str.replaceAll("\n", " ");

        String[] individualfeed = feed.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < individualfeed.length; i++) {

            if (individualfeed[i].contains("@")
                    ) {
                SpannableString redSpannable = new SpannableString(
                        individualfeed[i] + " ");

                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(\\w+)");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(individualfeed[i]);
                String str123 = null;
                if (m.find()) {
                    str123 = m.group(1);
                }

                int startFrom = 0;


                if (individualfeed[i].contains("@")) {
                    startFrom = individualfeed[i].indexOf("@");
                }


                if(individualfeed[i].trim().length()==1)
                {
                    builder.append(individualfeed[i] + " ");
                    continue;
                }

                // I am using Green Color in this code change it accordingly
                redSpannable.setSpan(
                        new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#00FF00")),
                        startFrom, individualfeed[i].lastIndexOf(str123) + 1,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                final String tag = (String) individualfeed[i].subSequence(
                        startFrom, individualfeed[i].lastIndexOf(str123) + 1);


                builder.append(redSpannable);

            } else {
                builder.append(individualfeed[i] + " ");
            }

        }

        return builder;

    }
```